# Create users via Puppet by reading a mySQL table

Tags: mysql, puppet

For a particular service, users are added/removed via web to a mySQL table. I need to replicate those users on several ubuntu servers (as regular shell users), preferably through Puppet. Currently I would use a shell script to read the table and create a users.pp manifest (but it gets tricky to deal with removed users). Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: You probably moved on a long time ago, but did you ever find anything?  Have you considered just switching your authentication over to ldap or some other centralized systems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agreed that you should be using LDAP instead of this. However, if you really want to use MySQL data to drive local user creation (which is not a great idea...)

Use the MySQL Hiera backend:
https://github.com/crayfishx/hiera-mysql